# pyobjc-3.0.3 Will not install on OS X 10.10

Tags: python, macos, pip, easy-install, pyobjc

`easy_install -U pyobjc-core` worked just fine, however I have tried `easy_install -U pyobjc` and `pip -U install pyobjc` and every other way you can think of (except probably the correct one) and they all return:

```
error: Setup script exited with error: This distribution is only supported on MacOSX versions 10.6 upto and including 10.8
```

Which doesn't make any sense, because wasn't pyobjc 3.0 created long after OS X 10.8 became outdated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version 3.1.1 of PyObjC was recently released and fixes this issue.

Comment: Awesome to hear! Now if I can remember what I was doing with this in the first place, I can get back at it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the issue:

https://bitbucket.org/ronaldoussoren/pyobjc/issue/103/pip-wheel-pyobjc-and-pip-install-pyobjc

If it has been fixed but not released, your only option is to install from source.